# Django REST framework: one method to return several fields

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've got a `ModelSerializer` for my API which has three custom fields that use the `serializers.SerializerMethodField` class. They look something like this:

```
field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
field2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
field3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_field1(self, obj):
    f1, _, _ = get_field_values(obj.attribute, obj.another_attribute)
    return f1

def get_field2(self, obj):
    _, f2, _ = get_field_values(obj.attribute, obj.another_attribute)
    return f2

def get_field3(self, obj):
    _, _, f3 = get_field_values(obj.attribute, obj.another_attribute)
    return f3
```

As you can see I'm calling the same function 3 times and getting the same result. I've tried overriding `__init__` but I can't seem to get access to each object in that case (just the `instance`, which is the full queryset). Is there a function I can override in which I can store these output values into a dict and just return the values one by one in my field methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere can be couple of ways you can avoid calling get_field_values three times, following is one which worked when I tried.

```
def get_all_f(self, obj, return_key):
    f1,f2,f3 = get_field_values(obj.attribute, obj.another_attribute)
    self.f = {'f1' : f1, 'f2' : f2, 'f3' : f3 }
    return self.f.get(return_key)

def get_field1(self, obj):
    f1 = self.f.get('f1', None)
    if f1 is None : 
        f1 = get_all_f('f1')        
    return f1

def get_field2(self, obj):
    f2 = self.f.get('f2', None)
    if f2 is None : 
        f2 = get_all_f('f2')        
    return f2

def get_field3(self, obj):
    f3 = self.f.get('f3', None)
    if f3 is None : 
        f3 = get_all_f('f3')        
    return f3
```

The idea is simple, store the variables in the object as cache. Check this cache variable before querying the database.

Comment: Good idea, didn't think of instantiating it when getting the first value. Thanks!